# GWT- Best way to give images for gwt application

Tags: gwt, image-uploading

which is the best way to serve images for the gwt application ...

eg: lot of images will be use by gwt app... image uploading,saving,changing, should be separate utility..

I have used Objectify once .. just want to know is there any better option ....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already used Objectify, I presume you are using App Engine as a hosting platform. Therefore, I recommend that you look at the Blobstore. More docs here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

The Blobstore is recommended to store and serve any user-uploaded pictures.

For static images, you should use GWT's ClientBundle and ImageResource (see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html).